# get the boot courtesy - idiom, meaning

Tags: meaning, idioms, word-usage

> It seems that William and Susan aren’t getting along very well together, so one of them
>   has got to go. Since William was there first, Susan will **get the boot courtesy** of the
>   delete statement...

Could you please explain the meaning and usage of the idiom **get the boot courtesy** in this sentence and exactly what kind of aspect the noun **courtesy** adds to the phrase?

Comment: There should be a comma after *boot*, which turns it into two idioms you can look up separately.

Comment: "Get the boot" and "courtesy of" are two separate idioms, that just happen to be next to each other here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Courtesy of the delete statement** : means *due to* / *thanks to* / *because of* the delete statement.

**Get the boot** : means **go** as clear in the previous context.

Answer (score 1):

**To get the boot** means to get kicked out of establishment. Courtesy here means that she will be forced to leave because he was first to settle down in flat/ apartment/house.